pymssql package '_bcp_batch' in Mac M3 chip
I have a Mac with M3 chip and I get an error when I use python3.10^:
File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 1, in init pymssql._pymssql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymssql/_mssql.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_bcp_batch'

my script:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import bi_pass

v_server = localhost
v_user = admin
v_password = 1234
v_database = mydb

source_engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pymssql://{v_user}:{v_password}@{v_server}:1433/{v_database}")
source_conn = source_engine.connect()

query = text( """ SELECT * from test""")
result = source_conn.execute(query)

rows = result.fetchall()
source_conn.close()
source_engine.dispose()

How can I fix it?
Thanks

one week later, any help?...
